# Windows RAS-VPN: cannot reach the entire network

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, rras

We did set up a Windows Server 2019 as a VPN-Server that should grant access to a /**22**-network.. It has a single Ethernet-connection to the network 192.168.**32**.0/**22** (spanning up to 192.168.**35**.255). The server's IP is 192.168.**33**.47 and the RAS-connection has 192.168.**33**.201.

But when opening the VPN-connection (split-tunneling enabled), I can only reach everything in 192.168.**33**.0/**24**. The remainder of the network is not reachable.

What do I need to change on the RAS-Server in order to reach the entire network?

The issue seems to be the routing-table (192.168.**110**.1 is the remote computer's gateway):

```
route print -4

Network destination       Netmask        Interface          Gateway Metric
            0.0.0.0       0.0.0.0    192.168.110.1   192.168.110.12     25
       192.168.33.0 255.255.255.0   192.168.33.200   192.168.33.208     26
(...)
```

Requests to 192.168.**32**.0/24 are thus routed to the local gateway 192.168.**110**.1 instead of 192.168.**33**.200.

The powershell confirms this:

```
Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress "192.168.33.5"
(...)
NextHop : 192.168.33.200 (good!)

Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress "192.168.32.5"
(...)
NextHop : 192.168.110.1 (wrong!)
```

I can edit the routing-table manually of course:

```
route add 192.168.32.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 192.168.33.200 METRIC 26
```

The whole target-network is reachable after that. But surely, it cannot be the solution to edit the routing-table on each client.

What do I need to change on the server-side in order to get this to work automatically?

Thank you very much!

Edit: As requested a screenshot of the configuration of the static route that I tried.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the output you have provided, the subnet mask for VPN client is /24. This will only allow it to access 192.168.33.0/24. There are few possible solutions.

1. Fix the subnet mask, for example, if you hare using DHCP to assign IP address, update the subnet mask to 255.255.252.0.
2. Add routes in the RRAS console, IP routing, Static Routes, Add new static routes for remaining networks, like 192.168.32.0/24 and point them the IP Address of server's NIC which is connected to LAN.

Comment: I tried option 2: a static route as described. But the route does not appear in the routing-table (route print -4) and a ping does not work.

Comment: Can you share the screen for RRAS where you entered Routes?

Comment: I added a screenshot in the post above (including the output of ipconfig /all).

Comment: Solved it: The static routes in the RRAS-console are not meant for the client, but for the server itself. In order to communicate routes to the client, the DHCP-Relay on the RRAS-Server needs to be configured and on the DHCP, you can use the option 121 to communicate static routes. These are then used by the RRAS-clients. And using a DHCP-policy it is possible to communicate these routes only to VPN-Clients (I only read about that yet and did not actually do it).
Thank you for your support!

Comment: OK, let me know if it works. I didn't have a Lab to test it, but I know that there is a way to send static routes. DHCP option 121 should work, but I have never done it myself. If all fails, I would say use a DHCP server to correct the subnet mask.

Comment: It worked fine in the lab-environment (just a normal Win10-PC with 32 GB RAM and a bunch of hyper-v-machines that I set up in about two days). But it took some reboots to get it to work, so I am not yet sure about the stability. In our real-world-systems, it does not work at all unfortunately. I will have to track that down next week.